# In PHP, how to pass session id along with file_get_contents function?

Tags: php, file-get-contents, sessionid

Why does this code cause the website to get stuck:

```
$id = session_id();
$url = 'https://www.website.com/dev/appointment?id='. $id .  
'';
$data = file_get_contents($url);
```

while everything goes well as planned when replacing $id with the actual session id like:

```
$id = session_id();
$url = 'https://www.website.com/dev/appointment?     
id=j8e3onreb4m71fljpcd9mesfr9';
$data = file_get_contents($url);
```

The PHP file accessed by the aforementioned URL starts with:

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET['id'])) session_id($_GET['id']);
session_start();
```

Comment: Define 'get stuck'.

Comment: @BenM It gets stuck loading...

Comment: And there are no errors output at all? You can't set a session ID before the session has actually started, so I doubt that your second snippet works as expected.

Comment: `session_start()` as the first thing on every page ;)

Comment: What's your dev server and other setup?

Comment: Why are you doing this?

Comment: What's the purpose of `. ''` in the `$url` assignment? I don't see a problem with it, it just seems unnecessary.

Comment: Are you sure the session ID is set in the first script? What does `echo $url` show?

Comment: I think server settings won't allow me to pass the seesion id in the URL

Answer (score 0):

You have to call session_start() before you call session_id, else $id will be empty

```
session_start();
$id = session_id();
$url = 'https://www.website.com/dev/appointment?id='. $id;
```

Comment: not mentioned in the code snippet, but session_start() has actually set an id. .....id='. $id .  
'' doesn't work while id=j8e3onreb4m71fljpcd9mesfr9 does.